# Map over key children

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I've a code with this format:

```
export const formatAgreementsData = (t, agreementsData, statesList) => agreementsData.map((item) => ({
  [t("tables:headers.name")]: item.full_name,
  [t("tables:headers.title")]: item.agreements.agreement_title,
...
```

It's creating a table row for every "item" (which is an "employee"). However, I want it to create a row for every "item.agreements". So, for example, an employee can have 5 agreements, I want it to create 5 rows repeating 5 times the full_name of the employee and iterating the title for every one of the 5 agreements owned by the employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Array.prototype.flat() to get what you want.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Something like :

```
export const formatAgreementsData = (t, agreementsData, statesList) => 
    agreementsData.map(item => 
        item.agreements.map(agreement => {
            return {
                [t("tables:headers.name")]: item.full_name,
                [t("tables:headers.title")]: agreement.title,
                ...
            }
        })
     ).flat()
```